# Unexpected type "never" in Typescript

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore

in my typescript code I am retrieving data from Firebase Firestore and filter the useful information in a forEach loop. I condensed my code to the following test function with the same error (all IDs are normally in variables):

```
async function test() {
  let playerOneData: FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData | null = null;
  let playerTwoData: FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData | null = null;
  const players = await db
    .collection("Games/ANY_ID/Players")
    .where(admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), "in", ["PLAYER1_ID", "PLAYER2_ID"])
    .get();

  players.forEach((doc) => {
    if (doc.id == "PLAYER1_ID") {
      playerOneData = doc.data();
    }

    if (doc.id == "PLAYER2_ID") {
      playerTwoData = doc.data();
    }
  });

  if (playerOneData == null || playerTwoData == null) {
    return null;
  }

  console.log(playerOneData.test + " " + playerTwoData.test);
}
```

At the end, when accessing the "test" property I get the error "Property test does not exist on type never".

I don't understand why it even should be of type never. In my understanding it should either be DocumentData or null (as defined) and I check for null directly before.

It would be nice if someone could hint me to the solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation of Typescript's control flow analysis. After assigning the value `null` to the local variables, their types are narrowed to `null` and then when you test if they're `null` to return from the function, `null` is eliminated from that narrowed type leaving `never` as the narrowed type.

Of course, the `forEach` loop ought to *widen* the type from `null` to `FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData | null`, but Typescript doesn't do this, because it isn't designed to know that this is the effect of passing this particular arrow function to the `forEach` method. In other circumstances, the arrow function might not reassign any variables from the outer scope and it would be annoying if the compiler was pessimistic so that simply calling `forEach` with any arrow function caused all narrowed types to be widened.

Typescript's design philosophy isn't to choose safety over convenience in all cases where there is such a trade-off, but it's difficult to balance the convenience of the compiler being optimistic vs. the safety of the compiler being pessimistic in this case, vs. the extra complexity required in the compiler to be able to decide on a case-by-case basis. [This issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) on the official issue tracker discusses this trade-off in more detail.

As a workaround for your case, you could replace the call to `forEach` with a regular `for` loop so that the variables aren't reassigned non-locally; in that case, the widening should occur as expected.